# How to select this element in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying some web automation. I want to select the button element. I tried to solve this but couldn't solve it

This is the button--------

```
<button class="dCJp8 afkep _0mzm-">
  <span class="glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7" aria-label="Like">
  </span>
</button>
```

**source-Instagram**

I tried these methods:

1. querySelector('button.afkep')
2. querySelector('button.dCJp8 .afkep ._0mzm-')
3. querySelector('button.dCJp8,.afkep,._0mzm-')
4. querySelectorAll('button.afkep')

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: looks ok for me. Just put document before the querySelector `document.querySelector('button.afkep')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use querySelectorAll() and getAttribute() method for returns the value of the attribute with the specified name, of an element.

Examples below.

```
var hearts = document.querySelectorAll(".glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9.u-__7")[0].getAttribute("aria-label");
```

for get velue of attribute "aria-label" in class glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9.u-__7

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.querySelector('button.dCJp8')` it works for me.